# Как записать attributes в JSON при создании вариаций через Rest API?

Tags: wordpress, json, api, woocommerce, rest

Проблема вот в чем, настроено добавление товаров через API, и она вроде как работала нормально, я точно не знаю, но сейчас дело в том, что товар создается нормально через API, добавляются атрибуты тоже нормально, но я не могу создать вариации из конкретных атрибутов.

```
{
    "type": "variable",
    "name": "My product 1",
    "description": "My product description 1",
    "regular_price": "200",
    "short_description": "Мое описание",
    "images": [
        {
            "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": 37,
            "name": "Фасовка",
            "slug": "pa_фасовка",
            "type": "nasa_label",
            "visible": true,
            "variation": true,
            "options": ["Коробка", "Штука"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Вот создание товара, на этом этапе все норм, атрибуты добавлены.
Дальше идет запрос на
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/product_id/variations/

```
{
    "regular_price": "150",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": 37,
            "name": "Фасовка",
            "option": "Коробка"
        }
    ]
}
```

и ничего, т.е. другие значения меняются нормально, вроде описания, цены, без проблем, но атрибуты всегда возвращаются пустыми, хотя по всем документациям при таком запросе в ответ все приходит нормально. Причем если создавать товар через админку и добавлять вариации вручную, то все норм, добавляются и при запросе приходят как надо
вот такой ответ приходит при работе через API:

```
"attributes": [],
```

а такой при ручном добавлении:

```
"attributes": [
        {
            "id": 37,
            "name": "фасовка",
            "option": "%d1%88%d1%82%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, дело было в названии ярлыка для атрибута, он должен быть на латинице)